# Dates on X Axis

Tags: r

I have looked everywhere ( [Example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4310629/plot-with-dates-as-x-axis-in-r)  ) and a few other posts, but I just cannot understand how to setup the date on the X axis.  Can someone help me?  This is what I have so far:

Data.CSV:

```
21-Oct-14,
22-Oct-14,
23-Oct-14,....etc
```

I have tried this: `axis(1,at=NVDA_Data$Date)`  and it doesn't show up and the console says its `NULL`

I just want to change where it says 0-250 with the dates

[image: What I have so far]

Comment: Did you try using the `label` argument to provide the text you want for the labels? Also, please post your code rather than linking to it.

Comment: Have a look at this recent post for ideas http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26506417/how-can-i-add-axis-ticks-for-dates-not-present-in-my-data-using-base-r-plot

Answer (score 1):

You can improve your question by letting us know you are using base R plot (which it appears from your screen shot to be true).

One easy solution is to convert your date-looking character or factor variable into a Date variable.  Plot will generally make reasonable axis marks from a Date variable. Use `summary()` on your data frame to determine if the Date variable is a factor or character. If it is a character, then do something like this:

```
data.frame$Date2 <- as.Date(data.frame$Date, "%d-%b-%y")
```

If your Date column is read in as a factor, use colClasses to read it in as character, then use the snippet above.

The link @user20650 provided gives some good tips for labeling Date variables.